# Restarting JBOSS EAP7 doesn't resume the service

Tags: centos, systemd, jboss

Look at the below output, I am trying to restart the JBOSS Eap7 application on CentOS7 but it doesn't resume back.

```
# ps -ef | grep java
jboss     2906  2837  2 12:31 ?        00:00:15 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss/standalone -c standalone.xml
root      3188  2245  0 12:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java

# systemctl status jbosseap7
● jbosseap7.service - JBoss EAP7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jbosseap7.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-11 12:31:30 EDT; 9min ago
  Process: 2791 ExecStop=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2824 ExecStart=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2837 (standalone.sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jbosseap7.service
           ├─2837 /bin/sh /opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
           └─2906 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -...

Jun 11 12:31:19 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Starting JBoss EAP7...
Jun 11 12:31:19 node01.local.com runuser[2835]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Jun 11 12:31:19 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[2824]: Starting jboss-eap: /
Jun 11 12:31:30 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[2824]: [  OK  ]
Jun 11 12:31:30 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Started JBoss EAP7.

# systemctl restart jbosseap7

# systemctl status jbosseap7
● jbosseap7.service - JBoss EAP7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jbosseap7.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-06-11 12:42:03 EDT; 2s ago
  Process: 3363 ExecStop=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3223 ExecStart=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2837 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 11 12:41:32 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Starting JBoss EAP7...
Jun 11 12:41:32 node01.local.com runuser[3235]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Jun 11 12:41:32 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3223]: Starting jboss-eap: /
Jun 11 12:42:03 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3223]: jboss-eap started with errors, please see server log for details
Jun 11 12:42:03 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3223]: [  OK  ]
Jun 11 12:42:03 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3363]: Stopping jboss-eap: [  OK  ]
Jun 11 12:42:03 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Started JBoss EAP7.

# ps -ef | grep java
root      3372  2245  0 12:42 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

***Starting the service again works fine. But here I am trying to narrow down the restart issue. So any pointers to narrow down this issue would really be appreciated.***

```
# systemctl start jbosseap7

# ps -ef | grep java
jboss     3478  3409 62 12:46 ?        00:00:10 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss/standalone -c standalone.xml
root      3596  2245  0 12:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java

# systemctl status jbosseap7
● jbosseap7.service - JBoss EAP7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jbosseap7.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-11 12:46:53 EDT; 9s ago
  Process: 3363 ExecStop=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3396 ExecStart=/opt/jboss/bin/init.d/jboss-eap-rhel.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3409 (standalone.sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jbosseap7.service
           ├─3409 /bin/sh /opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml
           └─3478 java -D[Standalone] -server -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -...

Jun 11 12:46:42 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Starting JBoss EAP7...
Jun 11 12:46:42 node01.local.com runuser[3407]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jboss by (uid=0)
Jun 11 12:46:42 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3396]: Starting jboss-eap: /
Jun 11 12:46:53 node01.local.com jboss-eap-rhel.sh[3396]: [  OK  ]
Jun 11 12:46:53 node01.local.com systemd[1]: Started JBoss EAP7.
```

Comment: so it is getting active and inactive again and again. right? If it is so, I will suggest you to kill all java process first and then start jboss service

Comment: Nope basically, it looks like the restart command is not able to flip the services. One the command start and stop seems to work. Restart doesn't seems to work at all.